# Question about proof in functional analysis book

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm currently working through introductory functional analysis from kreyszig, and I don't quite understand one of the proofs. this is it:

[image: proof]

My question is why it is necessary to go from $k = 1, 2, ...$ to the infinite sum. Why can't we just let $n\to\infty$ directly in (3)?

Comment: It is not clear what alternative you are proposing to the cited argument, "Why can't we just let $n\to \infty$ directly"?  Even if there were an alternative approach, the proof given in the cited text seems clear.  Do you really have a specific question about a step taken in this proof?

Comment: Well I think it's pretty clear what I'm asking here. I'm wondering why we can't go directly from (3) to (5) without going through the sums for $k = 1, 2, ...$. I agree that the proof is fairly clear, but without understanding why one of the steps is actually necessary I feel like I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Perhaps the clarity you seek would be better addressed by your giving the argument that you would use, and then we can judge whether it succeeds in jumping straight from (3) to (5) "directly", if I'm following you.

Comment: If $(a_n^{(k)})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence of non-negative real numbers for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then it does not follow without further assumptions that $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^{(k)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{k\to\infty} a_n^{(k)}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the answer. After thinking a bit about this, it does indeed answer my question.